# Weblogic connection pool with many ports

Tags: weblogic, port, connection-pooling

Today I've had a surprise. A customer told us that they have set two ports availables to connect to Oracle Server Database.

I don't know the reason to do this, but the problem comes because we are using a connection pool in Weblogic to access to Oracle Server, and till where I know, there is no capability to define two different ports in only one connection pool.

1. Why can anyone configure two different ports to access to DB Server?
   Which is the reason?
2. Can a connection pool have two different ports in its configuration? If it's possible, how can I do it?

The Weblogic Server is 12.1.2 and the Oracle Server is 11.2.0.2

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Cant you configure this in connection pool url - jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=IP1)(PORT=PORT1))
(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=IP1)(PORT=PORT2)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=SN)))

Comment: @Habin I think that you are talking about changing the `tnsnames.ora` in the Oracle Server, but what relation does it have with the connection pool in Weblogic? When I define the connection pool I need to add the Jdbc url connection `jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:port:SID` Can I link the pool connection with the tnsnames definition? Is this example that you did a way to do it?

Comment: ok. I got it wrong ! All the best to you.

Answer (score 0):

1: I am no DBA, so I can only answer WL specific questions.

2: Now to the one I can answer. One regular datasource can only have one port, since it follows the usual JDBC URL Syntax (jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port:sid)

But if you add a datasource for every host/port combination, you can combine multiple datasources to a "Multi data source" in Weblogic (tested in WL 12.1.3). To do this add a new "Multi data source" in the datasources menu, during the creation you can select all datasources which should be combined in this one. You can also select if they should be used in a failover or load balancing manner.